# How to insert a row into a table in MS SQL using Python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2008, pandas

when trying to insert a row into a table in MS SQL using Python pandas, I got the error " 'nonetype' object is not iterable" when trying to execute the INSERT query in python.I use Python 3.6 and microsoft sql server management studio 2008

my code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd 
server = 'ACER'
db = 'fin'
# Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')

# query db
sql = """INSERT INTO [fin].[dbo].[items] (itemdate, itemtype, name, amount)    VALUES('2017-04-01','income','bonus',350) """
#df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
print(df.to_string())
```

[image: The error]

Somebody suggested using SET NOCOUNT ON, so I tried to modify the query to:

```
sql = """ SET NOCOUNT ON
---
INSERT INTO [fin].[dbo].[items] (itemdate, itemtype, name, amount) VALUES('2017-04-01','income','bonus',350) """.split("---")
```

but the execution failed.

Comment: are you trying to insert the dataframe into SQL? Or just that line?

Comment: @MattR My idea is to create a website using sql database. when the users input their information, the data will be added to that database. Then I want to use some queries to extract the data and make some visualization with pandas